# How to receive event on Panel Controls?

Tags: c#, events

I have Form, it has 1 Panel and Panel has 0-N PictureBox's - dynamically added to the Panel, but if I take my mouse over the PictureBox and click on it, it don't fire any action. I mean when I click on Panel, it fire the click method, but how I can make sure that those PictureBox's also behave the same way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since picture boxes are added dinamically you need to attach event handelers for the click event in your code.

do somthing like this just before you add it to the control collection..

```
 PictureBox pbx = new PictureBox();
 pbx.Click += new EventHandler(pbx_Click);
 //Now assign other properties and then add it to control collection
 //panel1.Controls.Add(pbx);



private void pbx_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //handle the click event here
}
```

Comment: You mean: pbx.Click += new EventHandler(pbx_Click);

Answer (score 2):

Is your PictureBoxes are added dynamically to the Panel, then the Click event of the PictureBox  must also be added.

Note that you can handle all of the PictureBoxes Click event in the same handler:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                pb.Name = "pb" + i;
                pb.Click +=new EventHandler(pb_Click);
                this.Controls.Add(pb);
            } 

void pb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            PictureBox pb = (PictureBox) sender;
            if (pb.Name == "pb1")
            {
                ...
            }
        }
```

You get the idea...